# Return statements not printing outputs in class (specific)

Tags: python, class

I am trying to create a "Complex Number" class by myself. The attributes all work but with a twist. I cannot get the return statements to print.

```py
class Complex(object):
    
    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary_num = imaginary
        self.imaginary = str(self.imaginary_num)+"i"
        if self.imaginary_num > 0:
          self.imaginary = "+"+self.imaginary
        self.whole = str(self.real)+self.imaginary
    
    def __add__(self, no):
        if isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          new = Complex(self.real+no,self.imaginary_num)
          return new
        else:
          new = Complex(self.real+no.real,self.imaginary_num+no.imaginary_num)
          return new

    def __sub__(self, no):
        if isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          new = Complex(self.real-no,self.imaginary_num)
          return new
        else:
          new = Complex(self.real-no.real,self.imaginary_num-no.imaginary_num)
          return new
        
    def __mul__(self, no):
        if no == 0:
          return 0
        elif isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          a,b = (self.real*no),(self.imaginary_num*no)
          new = Complex(a,b)
          return new
        else:
          rr,rc,cr,cc = (self.real*no.real),Complex(0,self.real*no.imaginary_num),Complex(0,self.imaginary_num*no.real),(self.imaginary_num*no.imaginary_num)*-1
          if self.imaginary_num*-1 == no.imaginary_num:
            new = rr-cc
            return new
          else:
            new = Complex(rr*cc, rc*cr)
            return new
          
    def __truediv__(self, no):
        if no == 0:
          return None
        elif isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          a,b = (self.real/no),(self.imaginary_num/no)
          new = Complex(a,b)
          return new
        else:
          a,b = Complex(no.real, no.imaginary_num), Complex(no.real, -1*no.imaginary_num)
          new_used = Complex(self.real*b.real, self.imaginary_num*b.imaginary_num)
          new_odd = a*b
          new = Complex(new_used.real/new_odd, new_used.imaginary_num/new_odd)
          return new

    def mod(self):
        new = self.real**2+self.imaginary_num**2
        return new

c1=Complex(2,3)
c2=Complex(3,4)

c1+c2
```

If i use **.whole** attribute then the whole complex number is printed. But i cannot get it to print without the attribute
ex: *c1/c2*

I want this to print the returned number. How can i do this?

Comment: I have tried changing **repr** atribute to returning self.temp which i assigned all news just before return statements. No luck...

Comment: There is no `print` statement in your code ... why should it print anything?

Comment: Your `new` in the part of `__mul__` is not of type Complex - sometims you return an integer if I see that correctly. There is also no `__str__` nor `__repr__` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `__repr__` inside your class and return `self.whole` from there.

```
class Complex(object):

    def __init__(self, real, imaginary):
        self.real = real
        self.imaginary_num = imaginary
        self.imaginary = str(self.imaginary_num)+"i"
        if self.imaginary_num > 0:
          self.imaginary = "+"+self.imaginary
        self.whole = str(self.real)+self.imaginary

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.whole

    def __add__(self, no):
        if isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          new = Complex(self.real+no, self.imaginary_num)
          return new
        else:
          new = Complex(self.real+no.real, self.imaginary_num+no.imaginary_num)
          return new


    def __sub__(self, no):
        if isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          new = Complex(self.real-no, self.imaginary_num)
          return new
        else:
          new = Complex(self.real-no.real, self.imaginary_num-no.imaginary_num)
          return new

    def __mul__(self, no):
        if no == 0:
          return 0
        elif isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          a, b = (self.real*no), (self.imaginary_num*no)
          new = Complex(a, b)
          return new
        else:
          rr, rc, cr, cc = (self.real*no.real), Complex(0, self.real*no.imaginary_num), Complex(
              0, self.imaginary_num*no.real), (self.imaginary_num*no.imaginary_num)*-1
          if self.imaginary_num*-1 == no.imaginary_num:
            new = rr-cc
            return new
          else:
            new = Complex(rr*cc, rc*cr)
            return new

    def __truediv__(self, no):
        if no == 0:
          return None
        elif isinstance(no, int) | isinstance(no, float):
          a, b = (self.real/no), (self.imaginary_num/no)
          new = Complex(a, b)
          return new
        else:
          a, b = Complex(no.real, no.imaginary_num), Complex(
              no.real, -1*no.imaginary_num)
          new_used = Complex(
              self.real*b.real, self.imaginary_num*b.imaginary_num)
          new_odd = a*b
          new = Complex(new_used.real/new_odd, new_used.imaginary_num/new_odd)
          return new

    def mod(self):
        new = self.real**2+self.imaginary_num**2
        return new


c1 = Complex(2, 3)
c2 = Complex(3, 4)

print(c1+c2)
print(c1-c2)
print(c1/c2)
```

output:

```
5+7i
-1-1i
-0.8571428571428571+1.7142857142857142i
```